# Using different versions of Fancybox on the same page

Tags: jquery, fancybox, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin that uses Fancybox, but some people have themes and Fancybox plugins which have use versions.

Trying to use these versions means I'd need to write custom code to match different versions of Fancybox. To avoid this, I've decided to include my newer version of Fancybox with my plugin (only when I need it) and set it to a new jQuery attribute name (not `$.fancybox`).

I've [modified the orignal fancybox](https://github.com/aramkocharyan/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.init.js) source and added this function:

```
var jQueryCrayon = jQuery;
fancyboxInit(window, document, jQueryCrayon, 'crayonFancybox');
```

`fancyboxInit` will initialise `$.crayonFancybox` with my custom version of fancybox and my scripts will use this instead of `$.fancybox`, which will contain the old version of Fancybox loaded by the themes/plugins other users have. This avoids the two versions overriding the `$.fancybox` function and conflicting with ambiguous results.

Since I can't find this question being asked before, I've included it here for discussion. Is this the best way to handle such a case, or should I look for alternatives? jQuery also has `$.noConflict()` but this would involve making assumptions of the enqueue order of my scripts with those of the themes and other plugins, which may specify the same enqueue priorities and lead to ambiguity.

Comment: What do you mean by "ambiguous results"?

Comment: Using `$.fancybox` is nondeterministic - it could be my new version, or an old version from a theme or other plugin. Removing this and replacing it with my own isn't an option either, since it may be used elsewhere.

Comment: Are you saying that `$.fancybox` is going to be declared more than once and there is nothing you can do about it?

Comment: If you have two includes to fancybox it will be, but it's ambiguous because other users may or may not have fancybox in their themes and other plugins. So it's not reliable to use `$.fancybox` with the assumption it's your fancybox, and that loading in your fancybox didn't override the old version which the user needs.

Comment: So what is the problem with naming your version `$.myFancyBox`

Comment: The original script doesn't let you - "fancybox" is hard coded. You could copy it out, but would need to play around with enqueuing priorities and checking the version string.

Comment: Why cant you just modify the fancybox script in your project to have a slightly different name.

Comment: I did! But this script is dynamic in that nothing is hard coded, so it can be reused in another project by changing a single string without the need to re-minify the original source code.

Comment: 6 years later I find myself facing almost the same issue - did you find a better solution, Aram?

Comment: @Salvatore I ended up using this approach before having to replace it with Colorbox.

Comment: Unfortunately demo is not working